# How to solve application stopped work bug?

Tags: android, out-of-memory

My application is probably running out of memory or it is some issue with that. I have exception handling on application so if i got exception It is send to my email, it is good for debug, but recently I have got a strange issue, when I put my application to background and start 2-3 other application for example Gallery when i want to reopen my application instance it shows me Application stops work and no exception is send to me, so it is hard to solve, can you please help me to solve my issue, or handle that memory issue and restart the whole app instead of showing that the application has stopped worked.

thank you very much. It will also help if you show me how to simulate that memory issue when the application is in debug mode.

my manifest:

```
 <application
        android:name=".utils.JLApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="JustLook"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:launchMode = "singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/JLTheme">
```

I also think that maybe my application is correct but some of the libraries or something has stopped to work and that throws my application. But I am not sure of that. I also noticed that it happened frequently when i implemented google api connection and fuse location listener, but i am also not sure if it causes this kind of problem, maybe the memory issue is more likely bug here. But I dont know how to find it or solve it because it does not throws exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think that your problem is memory related.
According to how you describe your problem, i'm assuming that your crash is caused by a NullPointerException. 
As MarkySmarky described, Android kills background applikations to gather memory space.

So please have a look at your MainActivitys onResume or onStart. There must be some handlers, adapters, etc. that are null when you are resuming your app.

In addition, i would suggest to add [Crashlytics](http://try.crashlytics.com/sdk-android/) to your project. It tracks your crashes in detail. If have a crash report regarding your problem, please post it here.

Comment: I will i am triing to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I must say that the behaviour that you've described sounds perfectly normal besides that crash thing ;)

Android kills background applications when it needs to free up memory for other apps. The crash you're having MUST somehow be related to your code running in onCreate() of JLApplication. The best way to debug or find this bug is either start your application in debug mode or spread logs all around.

You can also take a look at Debug.waitForDebugger().

btw you should have a really good reason for having the following in you application tag - "largeHeap"

Comment: Thanks for advice if i solve it i will post the answer. thanks